# Spock and Maven. Tests with @Unroll failed with errors but placeholders is not filled with iteration data in Maven output

Tags: java, maven, groovy, spock

I have some parameterized test with Spock, and it's 10 cases which coming to test in where block. So, I decide to use @Unroll annotation so when some of the 10 cases fail, I will understand which one. 
So I add to feature placeholder with message about what kind of case it is, let's say it's

```
"Test with #message case"(String message, etc..){...}.
```

If I'll try to launch it in IDEA, output is looks like expected. (in the left side of the window where tree of tests is opened)

```
Test with SomeIterationMessage case: failed
Test with AnotherIterationMessage case: failed
```

But console IDEA output is looks like:

```
Condition not satisfied:

resultList.size() == expectedSize
|          |      |  |
[]         0      |  1
              false
 <Click to see difference>

at transformer.NameOfSpec.Contract. Test with #message case (NameOfSpec.groovy:220)
```

If I launch building the project by Maven through command line and this tests failed I just get messages like in IDEA Console output. So it's absolutely useless and like in the IDEA Console output.

```
Test with #message case: failed
Test with #message case: failed
```

So it does not replace placeholders with particular iteration data to get info about which iteration was crushed.
How to figure it out so the IDEA console output and the Maven outputs get it right? 'Cause if it impossible, this @Unroll annotation really piece of nothing. 'Cause in IDE test can pass with no problem, but in a big project with tons of dependencies it can crush when you build it, and you will never get why and which iteration failed cause output is telling you nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it's can be used with Maven with no problem. In the IDE we can use our panel with a tree of tests. It works fine as I said before.
And what about maven. Yes, it doesn't show anything in console output. But when the test was failed we can go to the

```
target\surefire-reports
```

In the root of our module which Maven generate for each of the class and fill with outputs, and get right name of iteration with actual iteration data.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: *************************.***MapReduceSpec
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 0.938 sec <<< FAILURE! - in *******************.DmiMapReduceSpec
MapReduce flow goes correctly for dataclass (contract)    (*******************.***MapReduceSpec)  Time elapsed: 0.185 sec  <<< ERROR!
```

Where value "(contract)" in the end of method string, has been taken from iteration parameter #message. So raw method name looks like

```
 "MapReduce flow goes correctly for dataclass (#message)"(){...}
```

Of course, it's not a very cool trick, but it's anyway much faster, then debug 20 or even more inputs in where block manually figuring out which is dead.

Comment: Sounds like Maven prints the method name, rather than the test name reported to it by JUnit (perhaps file a Maven issue). The fact that stack traces contain the method name is expected.